# Easiest way to create a large table from two tables of differing size

Tags: database, powerbi

My apologies if this is a basic question, however I cannot find a simple answer for it so I figured I'd ask here. I have two tables in PowerBI, one table(A) has 53 columns and the other(B) has 14. Some of the columns match and some do not.

> what is the simplest way to create a new table so that the new table has all columns(even ones that are only in A or B) and columns that match are merged?

If this requires more details please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append Queries in Query Editor.

Comment: Wow thanks, that is exactly what I'm looking for. I knew there had to be a simpler way than using DAX.